# Webform formatting question

Tags: webforms

I'm running Drupal 7.34 and Webform 7.x-4.9/Webform Layout 7.x-2.2.

I've put together a webform to be used for customers to fill out their data. If I select Label Display "Above", it disappears and no labels show. If I set it to "Inline" it works better, but the spacing is goofy (see [link](https://imgur.com/Y7oixKY)).

How do I set it so that the "Above" label display works, and how do I control setting up the spacing (so that I can have only one on a line)?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: For an example of the bad spacing, the Submit button is all over and the "Date of procedure" is in an odd spot.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a CSS issue with your template rather than a Webform/Drupal issue.

The webform module adds a default ".form-item" class to the wrapper DIV around each form element.

Try adding "clear:both;" to that class to force the form elements to vertically stack. Something like this:

```
.form-item {
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The webform module generates general form markup but it's up to your theme to display it. If your theme is not displaying forms correctly, you can either:

- Switch to a different theme.
- Use your browser's console to inspect elements and add some css to fix their positions.